# How to pass Array of Items as parameter to Stored Procedure In "MVC4 Razor"?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

Am working on a product Filter Page.The problem is i want to filter the product page based on the product color.Currently i could filter with one color,But when it comes to more than one it have to check in database with all these selected Colors.I dont know how to pass these values as parameter in MVC Razor.
Here is the code which i have tried with one color.

```
<script>
        $('.checked').click(function () {
               if (this.checked) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'FilterByColor',
                    data: { minimum_range: $("#minid").val(), maximum_range: $("#maxid").val(), color: $(this).attr('id') }, //--> send id of checked checkbox on other page
                    success: function (vlist) {
                        $('#card-group').empty();
                        for (var i in vlist) {

                            $('#card-group').append($('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 p-0"><div class="card product-men p-3"><div class="men-thumb-item"><img src="' + vlist[i].img1 + '" id="imgfront" class="card-img-top"><div class="men-cart-pro"><div class="inner-men-cart-pro"><a href="#" id="quickview" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>/</div></div></div><!-- card body --><div class="card-body  py-3 px-2"><h5 class="card-title text-capitalize" id="mname">' + vlist[i].mname + '</h5><div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-dark font-weight-bold" id="mprize">' + vlist[i].mprize + '</p><p class="line-through" id="mdprize">' + vlist[i].mdprize + '</p></div></div><!-- card footer --><div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end"><h3> <a href="Purchase/AddToCarts?mid=' + vlist[i].mid + ',mrate=' + vlist[i].mrate + '" class="hub-cart phub-cart btn">Add To Cart</a></h3></div></div></div>'));
                        }
                        //alert('it worked');
                        //alert(data);
                        //$('#container').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('it broke');
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert('it completed');
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    </script>
```

> Controller

```
public List<items> GetProductByColor(int? minimum_range, int? maximum_range,string color)
        {
            List<items> vlist = new List<items>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getWproductByColor", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprize", minimum_range);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eprize", maximum_range);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", color);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var g = new items()
                        {

                            mid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["mid"]),
                            mname = Convert.ToString(reader["mname"]),
                            mcode = Convert.ToString(reader["mcode"]),
                            mcolor = Convert.ToString(reader["mcolor"]),
                            mctype = Convert.ToString(reader["mctype"]),
                            mdetails = Convert.ToString(reader["mdetails"]),
                            mtype = Convert.ToString(reader["mtype"]),
                            mdprize = Convert.ToString(reader["mdprize"]),
                            mprize = Convert.ToString(reader["mprize"]),
                            mdate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["mdate"]),//DateTime.ParseExact("reader['mdate']", "ddd MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            msize = Convert.ToString(reader["msize"]),
                            mstock = Convert.ToString(reader["mcount"]),
                            img1 = Convert.ToString(reader["mimg1"]),
                            img2 = Convert.ToString(reader["mimg2"]),
                            img3 = Convert.ToString(reader["mimg3"])


                        };
                        vlist.Add(g);
                    }

                }
            }

            return vlist;
        }
```

> Stored Procedure

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getWproductByColor]
@sprize int,
@eprize int,
@color char(50)
as

BEGIN
select mid,LTRIM(RTRIM(mtype))as mtype,LTRIM(RTRIM(mname))as mname,LTRIM(RTRIM(mdetails))as mdetails,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcode))as mcode,LTRIM(RTRIM(mcolor))as mcolor,msize,LTRIM(RTRIM(mctype)) as mctype,convert(date,mdate)as mdate,mdprize,mprize,mcount,mimg1,mimg2,mimg3  from [dbo].[material] where mtype='women' and (mdprize between @sprize AND @eprize)and mcolor=@color order by mdprize asc;
END
```

Comment: You could convert the colours to a comma separated CSV and split them on the comma in the stored proc.

Comment: Try to do all work in SP which you are doing in the controller, it will make your work easier